# Python "requests" library targeting multiple redundant hosts

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

We have a Python library that uses the "requests" package and acts as a client to a HW device that provides a REST API. In the setup of the data centers, there are multiple redundant such HW devices. Any one of them can be used by the client library because they synchronize their data.

We would like to avoid setting up a load balancer that provides a single IP address for those redundant HW devices, and instead want to configure the Python client library with a list of target IP addresses or host names of these redundant HW devices, so that it uses anyone of them that currently works.

Is there a way to configure that in the Python "requests" library (or its underlying urllib3 library)?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the requests library to use a list of target IP addresses or hostnames for the redundant HW devices by creating custom `requests.Session` object and configuring the `HTTPAdapter` to use a custom `DNSResolver` that resolves the target IP addresses or hostnames dynamically.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager
import socket

class DynamicDNSResolver:
    def __init__(self, targets):
        self.targets = targets
        self.resolved = set()
        self.socket_cache = {}


    def resolve(self, host, port, *args, **kwargs):
        if host in self.resolved:
            return self.socket_cache[(host, port)]
        for target in self.targets:
            try:
                addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(target, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = addrinfo[0]
                sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
                sock.connect(sa)
                self.socket_cache[(host, port)] = sock
                self.resolved.add(host)
                return sock
            except socket.error as e:
                print(f"failed to connect to {target}: {e}")
                raise e

targets = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]
resolver = DynamicDNSResolver(targets)

session = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=0.1, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504])
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries, pool_connections=100, pool_maxsize=100)
adapter.poolmanager = SOCKSProxyManager(socks_version=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy_url="socks5://localhost:9050")
adapter.poolmanager.resolver = resolver
session.mount("http://", adapter)
session.mount("https://", adapter)

response = session.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: Does the "resolve()" method in the code above not need to be a method of class "DynamicDNSResolver"?

Comment: @AndreasMaier I'm sorry, it should be part of `DynamicDNSResolver` class, I just messed up formating

Comment: Jubick, I had to make two more changes to get over basic issues: socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 needed to be imported; removed socks_version arg from SOCKSProxyManager to avoid TypeError. After that, it still failed with connection refused, on a host that I can otherwise reach.
Does this solution need a SOCKS server running (sorry for the question but I'm not very fluent in SOCKS)?